# Ember observer / run schedule for each time a route is loaded

Tags: ember.js

I have a property in an Ember controller which has an observer. This is called when I first visit the page / route and also when I change the a dropdown that the value is bound to (as expected).

What isn't happening, is the observer being fired when I re-visit the page and the value is re-set (to the same value it was when I left the page).

The reason I need this, is that the value is used as a filter for another function and that function is called inside the observer.

Is there a way to make an observer fire even if the value is the same as it was before? 
Or alternatively, a sensible way to fire a function (perhaps via the run loop) from a controller, each time the controller is loaded / route visited?

Comment: The controller is a singleton. You can call resetController or setupController to (re)set properties.

Answer (score 0):

In setupController route hook, you will get `controller` reference so you can use that to call observer function.

```
setupController(controller,model){
    this._super(...arguments);    
    controller.get('testObserver')();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer below style to observe a property.

```
setupController(controller, model){
    if (this.get('somelogic')) {
        controller.addObserver('yourProperty', controller, this.get('callback'));
    }
}

resetController(controller, isExisting, transition) {
    if (isExisting) {
        controller.removeObserver('yourProperty', controller, this.get('callback'));
    }
}
```